# Joining up data from multiple sfdx force:data:tree:export outputs

Tags: salesforcedx, data, data-export, data-import, tree-export

I have a 3 level deep graph of records that I would like to export: parent records, child records and a grand-child records.

Reading this [Example: Export and Import Data Between Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_test_data_example.htm), I was interested to see this at the bottom of the page:

> Looking for a more complicated example? The easy-spaces-lwc sample app
> has a data plan showing how to import Accounts, related Contacts, and
> a 3-level deep custom object chain.

but when looking at that example it looks like only 2 levels deep i.e. [a parent object and 2 different immediate child objects](https://github.com/trailheadapps/easy-spaces-lwc/blob/develop/data/Market__c-Space__c-plan.json).

But on a closer look, there is also [this 3 level plan](https://github.com/trailheadapps/easy-spaces-lwc/blob/develop/data/Plan2.json) that is used for importing. But unclear how the middle layer - the Contact records - were created to have both a `referenceId` and to make `@` references. Manually?

Is there an easy way to go 3 (or more levels) deep using the [--plan](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342779/sfdx-tree-export-only-exports-200-records) option? See [more on --plan](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212034/what-are-saverefs-and-resolverefs).

In a single SOQL query it is only possible to query a parent and child and no deeper. (Yes the parent direction can be several levels deep but that is not a general solution to get all the grand-parent etc records as they may not have child records and so can be left out.)

Comment: does this one answer your question?
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/255711/16508

Comment: Hi @ytiq, It looks like it does, thanks; pretty painful sequence though. Not sure how to handle this here; think I'll propose to close this as a duplicate of that. I decided in the end to do my export in Apex code as I'm doing my input in Apex code and that way I can avoid the `--plan` files altogether.